# Move image in Android

Tags: java, image, move

In google I coulnd't search anything, only moving animation.
I want to move my "imgview" object. 5 pixels by 1 button click.
(I want to make a game. Every click button (arrow) hero walks 5 pixels up screen)
I think that this will be simple code.
I have relativelayout.

```
     button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

            //// something like hero._y = hero._y - 5

        }
        });
```

What code I must use?

Comment: *"<Easy> Move image in Android java"* 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) What makes you think it is `<Easy>` when you have no idea how to accomplish it?  That is kind of like saying "don't expect me to thank you for a solution - since this is just **so** easy.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {

             SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                         moveRight = settings.getInt("rightValue", moveRight) +5;
                        //---------------- moving imageview  ----------------------------------
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) alert.getLayoutParams();
                         params.setMargins(moveRight, 0, 0, 0);
                        alert.setLayoutParams(params);



    }
```

ok so this is how I did it, first I make an int for the directions you want to move I called mine moveRight, then make a SharedPreferences so your ImageView location will be saved each time you move it, make sure where you call "moveRight = settings.getInt("rightValue", moveRight) +5;" you don't forget to put how far you want to move the ImageView by adding either +5 (for moving right) or -5 (for moving left) like I already did there, the code after that is what you will need to actually move the ImageView, and the line that has "params.setMargins(moveRight, 0, 0, 0);" the next int after moveRight will move the ImageView up or down. you could probably copy and past this and it will work just fine as long as you import all the right stuff and you got all your buttons and int's declared

hope I was clear I'm not the best at english skills or giving understandable help LOL